# Why "ionic serve" does not run once I open project directory?

Tags: javascript, java, ionic-framework

[image: Screenshot of cmd]

It doesn't work as an internal or external system command, once I open up my project directory to run "ionic serve". Even though "ionic" is recognized as a system command. I have searched the internet but haven't found an answer yet that solves the problem.

Comment: Show us the print screen of CMD.

Comment: @Tomislav Stankovic...this error i get after hours of hardwork

Comment: I suggest to try to use more clear sentences. It wasn't trivial to understand, what are you talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try a global installation using option "-g"  : 
npm install -g ionic or  npm install -g cordova

Comment: i'm puzzled why it only gives errors when i run app in project directory..ionic command works in global path..so i'm thinking the problem lies in the user path of my system. Messed around a bit but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Delete data out of the [cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache) folder, [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) npm and then [install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) Ionic/Cordova. After that try to run `ionic serve`.

```
npm cache clean
npm update -g
npm install -g ionic cordova
```